# How to install Maxima CLI-only in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: apt, package-management, 20.04

I am attempting to install Maxima on Ubuntu 20.04 (on a headless server for use programmatically), but, unlike previous releases which had the graphical interface as a separate additional package, the `maxima` package in this release now seems to bring in a large number of X and Gnome dependencies.

Is there a way that I can install only the packages needed for the command line version of Maxima, as I would prefer not to bring in a whole X environment on to a headless server unnecessarily?

Answer (score 0):

You can take more control on Maxima installation by using special options to specify that you do not want to get recommended and suggested dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get install maxima --no-install-suggests --no-install-recommends
```

For example on minimal 20.04 LTS installation it will result in:

> ```
> Reading package lists... Done
> Building dependency tree       
> Reading state information... Done
> Suggested packages:
>   texmacs maxima-doc xmaxima maxima-emacs wish
> Recommended packages:
>   maxima-share gnuplot-x11
> The following NEW packages will be installed:
>   maxima
> 0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
> Need to get 6928 kB of archives.
> After this operation, 53.5 MB of additional disk space will be used.
> Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 maxima amd64 5.43.2-3 [6928 kB]
> Fetched 2494 kB in 1s (3163 kB/s) 
> Selecting previously unselected package maxima.
> (Reading database ... 62984 files and directories currently installed.)
> Preparing to unpack .../maxima_5.43.2-3_amd64.deb ...
> Unpacking maxima (5.43.2-3) ...
> Setting up maxima (5.43.2-3) ...
> Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.1-1) ...
> ```

Analyzing the above output we can see that `gnuplot-x11` may be a reason to install X11 stuff.